# Time of process computation with MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I have the program which calculate integral by using MPI. This is the code (trapezoidal rule, by using external function included in `trap1.h` file):

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "get_data.h"
#include "trap1.h"

extern double trap1(int n1, int n2, double a, double h);
extern void Get_data(int* n, int m, int d);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int world_size, world_rank, i, N, N1, N2;
    double Sum, GSum, A, B, h, time1, time2, x, ISum,time;
    MPI_Status Status;
    A=0.0;
    B=1.0;
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    Get_data(&N, world_rank, world_size);
    if(world_rank==0) time1=MPI_Wtime();
    N1 = N*world_rank/world_size+1;
    N2 = N*(world_rank+1)/world_size;
    h=(B-A)/N;
    Sum = trap1(N1,N2, A, h);
    FILE * pFile;
    if(world_rank==0) {
        GSum = Sum;
        for(i=1;i<world_size;i++)
        {
            MPI_Recv(&ISum,1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Status);
        }
        time2 = MPI_Wtime();
        GSum=GSum/N;
        time = time2-time1;
        printf("Result = %et Time = %et Intervals: %dn",GSum,time,N);
        FILE * pFile;
        pFile = fopen ("time1_1.log","a");
        fprintf (pFile, "number of procs is %it time= %ft cost = %it", world_size, time, world_size*time);
        fclose(pFile);
    }
    else MPI_Send(&Sum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I need to get the calculation time for each process (i.e., I want to calculate the period of time during which process `i`, where `0 <= i < world_size`, was running). Unfortunately, all of my attempts were unsuccessful. If I understand correctly, I need to get the value

```
MPI_Wtime() - time1
```

where `time1` is the program initialization value, for each process. But I don't understand exactly in which part of my code this value gives the calculation time for processes.

I've inserted the code

```
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen("time0_1_1.log","a");
fprintf (pFile, "particular_time=  %f\t",  MPI_Wtime() - time1);
fclose(pFile);
```

into the program code after

```
MPI_Recv(&ISum,1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Status);
```

line. But I'm not sure that the time I've obtained is really the time of particular processes.

Could You help me?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : so first You propose to greate an array for time on particular process?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : how do You think, does my code which is beginned from "FILE * pFile" (in the bottom of my question) the one which gives the correct time for each executing process?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : it prints some time into the file, but these times are arranged in ascending order, so I'm not sure about what exactly these times mean.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you want to measure and I fear so do you. You may have some misconceptions of the essential SPMD paradigm of MPI. Can you try to clarify what metric you actually want to measure - and how the results should be distributed?

Comment: @Zulan : I want to get the time of calculation of the integral's part on particular process (in general - on all of processes). That's not the time before calculation and after collecting all of particular integrals and making the summation over all of these integrals.

Comment: If you record `MPI_Wtime` before and after the calculation on the particular process and compute the difference, you have exactly that. What are the issues you run into when trying it?